# Shortening Oracle SQL containing several unions

Tags: sql, oracle

I believe the provided code can be rewritten shorter. Now one block is basically copy-pasted. In reality I have 6 such blocks.

This would be the data:

```
WITH
x(id, yr, more_info) AS
    (SELECT 1, 2020, 'info1' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 2021, 'info2' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 3, 2021, 'info3' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 4, 2020, 'info4' FROM DUAL )
,
n(n_id, n_id2, n_year) AS
    (SELECT 1, 3, 2021 FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 4, 2021 FROM DUAL )
```

Desired result - complemented table `x` with up-to-date column `yr` values and info taken from previous year:
[image]

Current code:

```
WITH
x(id, yr, more_info) AS
    (SELECT 1, 2020, 'info1' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 2021, 'info2' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 3, 2021, 'info3' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 4, 2020, 'info4' FROM DUAL )
,
n(n_id, n_id2, n_year) AS
    (SELECT 1, 3, 2021 FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 4, 2021 FROM DUAL )
     
SELECT * FROM x

-- ========>  BLOCK_1 for column n_id  <=========
UNION
SELECT n_id, n_year, more_info 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM x
      WHERE (id, yr) IN (SELECT id, MAX(yr)
                         FROM x
                         GROUP BY id) ) t1,
     (SELECT n_id, n_year
      FROM n
      WHERE (n_id, n_year) NOT IN (SELECT id, yr
                                   FROM x) ) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.n_id

-- ========>  BLOCK_2 for column n_id2  <========
UNION
SELECT n_id2, n_year, more_info 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM x
      WHERE (id, yr) IN (SELECT id, MAX(yr)
                         FROM x
                         GROUP BY id) ) t1,
     (SELECT n_id2, n_year
      FROM n
      WHERE (n_id2, n_year) NOT IN (SELECT id, yr
                                   FROM x) ) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.n_id2
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a possibility employing `UNPIVOT`

```
WITH
x(id, yr, more_info) AS
    (SELECT 1, 2020, 'info1' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 2021, 'info2' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 3, 2021, 'info3' FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 4, 2020, 'info4' FROM DUAL )
,
n(n_id, n_id2, n_year) AS
    (SELECT 1, 3, 2021 FROM DUAL UNION 
     SELECT 2, 4, 2021 FROM DUAL )
     
SELECT * FROM x
UNION
SELECT id2, n_year, more_info 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM x
      WHERE (id, yr) IN (SELECT id, MAX(yr)
                         FROM x
                         GROUP BY id) ) t1,
     (SELECT * FROM n
      UNPIVOT(
          id2
          FOR id_type
          IN (n_id, n_id2) ) ) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id2
```